# Google Play, problemas Políticas Privacidad con One Signal - App retirada

Tags: android, app, google-play, google-play-console, onesignal

tengo un problema con una app que me han retirado después de varios años publicada.

Me dicen que como mi app usa One Signal tengo que avisar en las políticas de privacidad. Así que actualicé las políticas y añadí un parrafo hablando de que OneSignal usa los datos para enviar notificaciones. Pero parece que no les basta con eso porque me han rechazado la actualización. Realmente no sé qué es lo que tengo que hacer. Y me da miedo dar muchos pasos en falso porque capaces de bloquearme la cuenta por una tontería.

Aquí expongo los mensajes que me mandan, el original en inglés, el traducido por traductor y el párrafo que añadí en mi política de privacidad.

Si alguien me pudiera dar una pequeña orientación estaría muy agradecido.

**Mensaje de rechazo de actualización en inglés:**
[image: Mensaje de rechazo de actualización en inglés]

**Mensaje de rechazo de actualización traducido:**
[image: Mensaje en inglés]

**Fragmento de mis políticas de privacidad:**
[image: Mis políticas de privacidad]

Comment: Creo que [este artículo](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11150561) te será de utilidad. Aplicando lo dicho ahí, y llenando correctamente el formulario de Play Console sobre la privacidad de los datos al momento de subir la nueva versión de la aplicación no deberías tener problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Debiste recibir previamente emails para realizar los cambios necesarios, estos avisos deben ser atendidos, para evitar la pausa en las actualizaciones, o que nuestra aplicación sea removida.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ve a Google Play Console en la sección Política y programas el apartado "Contenido de aplicación", **debes asegurar tener una url donde se defina la Política de Privacidad de tu aplicación, no únicamente la de OneSignal.**

> Cuando incluyes una política de privacidad en tu ficha de Play Store,
> proporcionas a los usuarios más información sobre cómo utilizas sus
> datos sensibles y los de su dispositivo

Seguramente debes tener algún otro cuestionario a llenar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El caso es que eso ya lo tengo hecho. Tengo mi política de privacidad y un fragmento de OneSingal, que supuestamente afecta a mi app. Optaré por desactivar OneSignal.